# Laravel Package for XML API Usage

Tags: xml, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-api, chasepayment

Is there any laravel package for XML Api usage?
I am developing one project using Laravel and I came to know that chase payment gateway doesn't get sdk for php.
So is there any package to use XML api directly in laravel?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote several helpful XML packages for Laravel.

[Response XML: This one adds an xml method to the Response class](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml).

E.g. `return response()->xml(User::all());`

[Request XML: This one lets your api receive an incoming xml request and parse it so it can be run through Laravel's built in validation](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/request-xml).

[Collection XML: This one adds an xml method to Laravel's native Collection class](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/collection-xml).

Sounds like you may want to use this one if you're preparing data to send off to some other API that consumes XML. You can load your data into a collection and transform it into XML. E.g. `$collection->toXml();`